# Help translating a phrase

Tags: translation

I've heard this japanese sentence in a dialog:

```
nihon no inu wa gohan o tabe masuka?
```

I can't translate it. 
"Do japanese dogs eat anything?"
Or "do you eat japanese dogs?"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the most basic knowledge of particles like "wo"...

[ごはん](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%94%E9%A3%AF) (gohan) in such a context means "rice", not meal in general.

The sentence (normally) means "Do Japanese dogs eat rice?", to which the answer is yes sometimes.